# Error fixed: use of unstable library feature 'build_hasher_simple_hash_one'

Tags: anchor, solana-program, solana-cli, anchor-lang

If this day you get an error like this:

```
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'build_hasher_simple_hash_one'
   --> src/random_state.rs:463:5
    |
463 | /     fn hash_one<T: Hash>(&self, x: T) -> u64 {
464 | |         RandomState::hash_one(self, x)
465 | |     }
    | |_____^
    |
    = note: see issue #86161 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86161> for more information
    = help: add `#![feature(build_hasher_simple_hash_one)]` to the crate attributes to enable

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
error: could not compile `ahash` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Add ahash to your dependencies!

```
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "."
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "foo"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
ahash = "=0.8.6"
```